# Is it possible to view the GR metric as a fluid in Newtonian physics?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, metric-tensor

I'm just wondering, are there any existing formulations of General Relativity where instead of thinking about objects following geodesics in spacetime, they are instead objects sitting inside a "fluid", and being pushed around by forces exerted by the fluid?

Comment: [The river model of black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060) has some relevance, but this model is not applicable to GR in general.

Comment: special relativity developed formally in order to fit data that could not be fitted with Newtonian mehcanics.  SR is within the formalism of GR thus no Newtonian fluid can possibly fit the data that NM could not fit ab initio.